# XLIB - All attempts to draw on display surface fail with "BadRequest"

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

Due to confidentiality agreements (defense sector work) I cannot post any real code.  But I have been stumped for weeks on this problem - and I have read every discussion thread I can find on StackOverflow and everywhere else to no avail.  We're stumped over here and I am requesting advice or  asking if anybody has seen or beat this issue.

Basic overview of the task is:

Find and manipulate a running Firefox browser on a specific display.  I need to do the following:

1. Find the running browser instance.
2. Position & Size the browser to a specific location on the display.
3. Position the icon if/when the application is minimized.
4. Implement "always on top" behavior for the browser - yes we know this is a no no but in our specific case this is needed, expected, and ok.

In order to implement the above I am calling the following X APIs (in order of the above):

1. `XOpenDisplay`, `XQueryTree`, `XGetWindowProperty`
2. `XMoveResizeWindow`
3. {not researched yet but I think I can do what I want with a window hint}
4. `XRaiseWindow`, `XNextevent`

The observed behavior is:

- Any API that does **NOT** draw on the display surface succeeds {except for `XGetNextEvent` - which crashes the application}
- All APIs that act on the display surface directly - `XMoveResize` etc... - fail with error code (1) "BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)"

Does anybody have a thought on what might be happening to us?  Any ideas would be appreciated!!  Additional info follows:

- x64 bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.2
- NVIDIA graphics hardware
- XLIB 7.1.1

Thanx in advance for any assistance...

Comment: I am wondering if your `Display *` is incorrect.  It seems strange that `XNextEvent()` would crash. Can you access the X logs and provide a pertinent section of those in your question?